# useeffect() run and set data to the variable after the return() run in react? how to handle this?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

```
export default function Education() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/").then((res) => {
      setProjects(res.data);
      console.log(res.data);
    });
  }, [projects]);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
          <Typography variant="h4" color="secondary">
            Some of my work
          </Typography>
        </Grid>

        {projects.map((project) => {
          return <p key={project.id}>{project.name}</p>;
        })}

      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want to get data from the api whenever the page gets render but what is happening is,

1. the variable project initialized with null
2. the return () runs where projects.map() function is.
3. As projects variable does not have any data so the map is not a valid function to run on projects.
4. And then the useeffect() is running.

thats why i'm getting Error:

**TypeError: projects.map is not a function**

how can i solve this. i'm new to react. Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need to specify project in the useEffect, just use an empty array.
Since you are using useState and storing the value of project. Keeping it on useEffect will made an infinite call.
Also check for `projects.length` while using map function

```
useEffect(() => {
 axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/").then((res) => {
  setProjects(res.data);
  console.log(res.data);
 });
}, []);
 return (
  <div className={classes.root}>
  <Grid container spacing={3}>
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
      <Typography variant="h4" color="secondary">
        Some of my work
      </Typography>
    </Grid>

    {projects.length && projects.map((project) => {
      return <p key={project.id}>{project.name}</p>;
    })} 

  </Grid>
</div>
);
```

Comment: ok checking the length really helped. i think now it does not go with the error and wait for the data to get called . second i used [projects] passed as parameter, not using that renders the data alternatively. but using it as parameter work fine. thanx

Answer (score 0):

Make the default value for projects an array so it doesn't return an error:

```
 const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);
```

currently it is an object (and not null as you said it is).

Also, update your `useEffect` and do not pass `projects`:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/").then((res) => {
      setProjects(res.data);
    });
  }, []);
```

or else it will crash your app as it will create an infinite loop (if the `projects` keeps changing), because it will trigger the useEffect everytime you update the projects.

Comment: 1st, im getting in json format so how can i set a default value to it. And will setting a default value will help me to get data which i actually want. 2nd , i tried removing projects from the [ ] it also does not helped. sometimes it return data at console and sometimes it dont.

Comment: then you need to have a fallback for the res.data